# SQLite optimization

Tags: database, optimization, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I consider to use SQLite in a desktop application to persist my model.
I plan to load all data to model classes when the user opens a project and write it again when the user saves it. I will write all data and not just the delta that changed (since it is hard for me to tell).

The data may contain thousands of rows which I will need to insert. I am afraid that consecutive insertion of many rows will be slow (and a preliminary tests proves it).

Are there any optimization best practices / tricks for such a scenario?

EDIT: I use System.Data.SQLite for .Net

Comment: Looks like you're not needing the database for anything other than data storage. Flat files are more efficient.

Comment: Future versions will need to upgrade data (add fields, tables etc). I think data / schema migration should be much easier with DB than with files (e.g. I just run a sql script).

Comment: do you begin a transaction prior inserting the rows? Otherwise SQLite's insertions are slow.

Comment: If you're loading and saving everything at one time, I'd go for flat files too. Relational representation is a pain to map to objects. In Java its pretty easy to load/save your object if they are serializable. I imagine C# or VB would have similar features.

Comment: I see two problems with serialization:

1. data format is coupled with class format. any refactor in the class would require data migration. it is much easier to migrate sql data than flat files.

2. db is a neutral format which other applications can later use. serialization is coupled to a specific implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Nick D said: If you are going to be doing lots of inserts or updates at once, put them in a transaction. You'll find the results to be worlds apart. I would suggest re-running your preliminary test within a transaction and comparing the results.